# Maximize product of die

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, independence, dice

> Suppose you have two fair 6-sided dice. Your goal is to maximize the
> product and you are allowed to replace one of the two die with a
> reroll if you'd like. What is the expected value of the product of
> these values assuming optimal play?

[image: My work]

This is my work however, my python script is getting $\simeq 17.14$. Is my work wrong?

Comment: One die, two dice.

Comment: @JohnDouma Dice is ok to use as singular. "The singular form for dice is originally die. But modern English now considers dice as both singular and plural nouns because of how language evolves."  https://grammarist.com/usage/dice-die/

Comment: @user4894 I disagree with that article. I have heard many persons call a request an ask but that is really poor English. Speaking is like making music. How do you want to sound?

Comment: @JohnDouma Only posted a link to an article. Not a hill I want to, uh, die on.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is wrong ($D1$ and $D2$ are not independent) and your script is probably correct. The actual value is $\frac{617}{36} \approx 17.13889$.

To calculate this, consider the expected product for each of the $36$ equally likely pairs of initial rolls if you reroll when the lower initial value is $3$ or less, so $D_1 \times \max(D_2, 3.5)$:

```
Rolls   1       2       3       4       5       6
                            
1       3.5     7       10.5    14      17.5    21
2       7       7       10.5    14      17.5    21
3       10.5    10.5    10.5    14      17.5    21
4       14      14      14      16      20      24
5       17.5    17.5    17.5    20      25      30
6       21      21      21      24      30      36
```

and take the average of the values in the $6\times 6$ array.

This is easy to encode.  To find the equivalent with $20$-sided dice in R:

```
n <- 20 
productwithreroll <- function(x,y){
    ifelse(x > n/2, ifelse(y > n/2, x*y, x*(n+1)/2),
                    ifelse(y > x, y*(n+1)/2, x*(n+1)/2))
    }
mean(outer(1:n, 1:n, productwithreroll))
```

and this gives $160.20625$, which is $\frac{25633}{160}$.

If you take the slower route and battle through the sums of squares and products etc., you get

for $n$ odd $\dfrac{71{{n}^{4}}+116 {{n}^{3}}+22 {{n}^{2}}-20 n+3}{192n^2}$,

and for $n$ even $\dfrac{71{{n}^{4}}+116 {{n}^{3}}+40 {{n}^{2}}-8 n}{192n^2}$,

both of which are $O(n^2)$, as you might intuitively guess.

Comment: Is there a quicker way to compute this? Suppose the die was 20 sided?

Comment: @shrizzy I have added to my answer